# Series voltage regulator circuit impedance mismatching while doing multisim simulation

Tags: voltage-regulator

In my project,I have to design a series voltage regulator circuit with the specifications of **o/p voltage as 9V,max. current as 1.5 A and short circuit current as 0.75 A**.While designing the circuit from scratch,we used transformer and rectifier circuit,we saw in  our simulations that the voltage after the filter is getting changed by a great amount.It may be because of mismatch of impedance in latter circuit and the former circuit.But I am not able to decide what should I do to achieve the goal.I am getting the solutions if I do the simulation by attaching a ac voltage with some  dc offset(for ripples).
The maximum capacitance available to me is 2 mF.
I am considering it as impedance mismatch because the voltage at the terminals of the former circuit is changing when the latter circuit is connected it.
Here is the attached simulation reports and the circuits:

[image: Ckt. not working]

[image]

Comment: Your "goal" is undefined, your circuit is covered in yellow text boxes and your definition of the problem (the voltage after the filter is getting changed by a great amount) is useless to anyone able to help you. Added to this your assertion that an impedance mismatch may be the problem makes no sense. Also, you don't appear to have asked a proper question.

Comment: ~5 Vpp of ripple when using a 2 mF capacitor with a 1.5 A load sounds about right to me. What exactly do you think the problem is? If you want less ripple, you'll need to use a lot more capacitance.

Comment: @DaveTweed I have the maximum capacitance available to me as 2 mF.Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Define the problem - nobody here can read your mind.

Comment: @Andyaka I am trying to say that when my rectifier circuit is disconnected from the latter part of the circuit,it is working fine(voltage is constant across the capacitance) but when they are connected the voltage starts varying.According to me,the reason can be impedance mismatching of both the circuits or the loading effect.

Comment: Sure, the alternative is to design your regulator so that the input ripple doesn't matter (i.e., is not passed to the output). A good first step would be to replace the crude linear regulator with a modern switchmode DC-DC converter. An additional advantage would be the efficiency -- only about 500 mA would be drawn from the capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to say that when my rectifier circuit is disconnected from
> the latter part of the circuit,it is working fine(voltage is constant
> across the capacitance) but when they are connected the voltage starts
> varying.

Consider a simple half wave rectifier fed from an AC supply via a transformer: -

[image]

The load is just a simple resistor. The output waveform is as you would expect - the diode is not conducting when the AC voltage goes negative. Now consider what happens when you also have a capacitor: -

[image]

The capacitor gets charged to the peak of the AC voltage waveform (ideal diode) then, when the diode is reverse biased du to the AC voltage starting to reverse, there is a slight discharge on the capacitor's voltage. This is due to the load taking current from the capacitor and discharging it. The capacitor gets re-plenished when the diode becomes forward biased again. The red line is the actual output voltage across the load resistor and, if R is lowered then the ripple seen is deeper. If C is lowered the ripple also becomes deeper. Full wave scenario: -

[image]

The great thing about a full wave rectifer (bridge) is that the capacitor gets replenished twice as often compared to a half wave rectifier but you still have ripple when the load resistor is connected.

So, if you can't alter the load you must increase the capacitor. Alternatively you use a buck regulator to feed your load - it will take less current because it is more efficient than a linear regulator.

> According to me,the reason can be impedance mismatching of both the
> circuits or the loading effect.

Impedance mismatch is something else entirely and is associated with transmission lines or the need to extract maximum power that a circuit can supply. Impedance mismatch also applies to linear circuits and not highly non-linear rectifiers.

It's the effect of the load being too great for the capacitance used.